# How to create a sequence of strings in a generated XSLT file?

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

I am trying to write an XSLT "X_start" that constructs another XSLT "X_generated" from an xml file containing rules. My problem is to create a sequence for comparisons beween what I come across in the xml file and what I've generated in X_generated. The idea is to do this comparison, and if this doesn't match I will generate some text. In my examples I am comparing if I actually can find the value, because if I try to see if the value is outside the allowed values, I will always succeed unfortunately.

The attribute value "conditional" means that if the template matches, then the used value must be according to some set of values.

Any help/hint is appreciated, and let me know if you want me to clarify something.

Example on rules:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rules>
    <rule type="conditional">
        <xPath>//elemA/@attribute1</xPath>
        <val allow="A"/>
        <val allow="B"/>
    </rule>
    <rule type="conditional">
        <xPath>//elemC/@attribute1</xPath>
        <val allow="C"/>
        <val allow="D"/>
    </rule>
    <rule type="conditional">
        <xPath>//elemB</xPath>
        <val allow="one"/>
        <val allow="two"/>
        <val allow="three"/>
    </rule>
</rules>
```

My current draft XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:axsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/TransformAlias"
    version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="true" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
    <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="axsl" result-prefix="xsl"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <axsl:stylesheet>
            <xsl:attribute name="expand-text" select="'true'"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="version" select="'3.0'"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="rules/*"/>
        </axsl:stylesheet>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="rule">
        
        <!-- This creates ("A", "B") -->
        <xsl:variable name="vals_from_for_each" as="xs:string*">
            <xsl:for-each select="val/@allow">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        
        <!-- This also creates ("A", "B") -->
        <xsl:variable name="vals_from_seq_text" as="xs:string*">
            <xsl:sequence select="val/@allow"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        
        
        <axsl:template>            
            <xsl:attribute name="match" select="xPath"/>
            
            <!-- Attempt to move the sequence into the generated template -->
            <axsl:variable name="vals" as="xs:string*">
                <!-- But this generates "A B", and is therefore not valid for comparison. 
                    I cannot compare a value like ". = A B", it needs to be ". = ('A', 'B')-->
                <xsl:sequence select="$vals_from_seq_text"/> 
            </axsl:variable>
            <axsl:if test=". = $vals">
                <axsl:message>Success</axsl:message>
            </axsl:if>
            
            <!-- trying by building a comparison tree (that doesn't work either... -->
            <axsl:variable name="value_list" as="element()*">
                <root>
                    <xsl:for-each select="val/@allow">
                        <val><xsl:value-of select="."/></val>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </root>
            </axsl:variable>
            
            <axsl:if test=". = $value_list/root/val">
                <axsl:message>Found in tree - Success</axsl:message>
            </axsl:if>
        </axsl:template>
    </xsl:template>
```

Resulting XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    expand-text="true"
    version="3.0">
    <xsl:template match="//elemA/@attribute1">
        <xsl:variable name="vals" as="xs:string*">A B</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test=". = $vals">
            <xsl:message>Success</xsl:message>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:variable name="value_list" as="element()*">
            <root>
                <val>A</val>
                <val>B</val>
            </root>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test=". = $value_list/root/val">
            <xsl:message>Found in tree - Success</xsl:message>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//elemC/@attribute1">
        <xsl:variable name="vals" as="xs:string*">C D</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test=". = $vals">
            <xsl:message>Success</xsl:message>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:variable name="value_list" as="element()*">
            <root>
                <val>C</val>
                <val>D</val>
            </root>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test=". = $value_list/root/val">
            <xsl:message>Found in tree - Success</xsl:message>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//elemB">
        <xsl:variable name="vals" as="xs:string*">one two three</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test=". = $vals">
            <xsl:message>Success</xsl:message>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:variable name="value_list" as="element()*">
            <root>
                <val>one</val>
                <val>two</val>
                <val>three</val>
            </root>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test=". = $value_list/root/val">
            <xsl:message>Found in tree - Success</xsl:message>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So none of the messages triggers, I fail in creating some comparable thing in my resulting XSLT. Any created sequence is created as separate values in a string(?), and I cannot do a lookup in the generated tree segment (which I guessed wouldn't work, but desperate as one can be, I tried anyway).
While writing this, I started thinking that one way could be to use a separate mode where I could create a completely separate xml document with lookup values, but this seems a bit worse than creating a lookup within each template. So, any ideas on how I can transfer my allowed values from my source XML to the generated XSLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahm... Taking a hint from Michael Kay's answer, why don't you bypass the entire "sequence of strings" issue and do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="rule">
    <axsl:template match="{xPath}"> 
        <axsl:variable name="vals">
            <xsl:copy-of select="val"/>
        </axsl:variable>     
        <axsl:if test=". = $vals/val/@allow">
            <axsl:message>Success</axsl:message>
        </axsl:if>
    </axsl:template>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Ok, so this also works. Wondering why my built variable  (that only had text content) that looks kind of similar didn't work for comparison?

Comment: Which variable are you referring to?

Comment: I tried creating a variable with elements called "value_list". But I'm guessing it has something to do with variables and context?

Comment: I would need more time to investigate this, but I believe your attempt using the `$value_list` variable will work if you remove the `as="element()*"` attribute.

Comment: I tried removing the `as="element()*"` attribute. This also works, and when debugging in Oxygen, I see that it creates a `document-node/<#document/fragment>`, as does `copy-of`.

Comment: Yes. Alternatively, you could keep the `as` attribute but then you would need to change the test from `test=". = $value_list/root/val"` to `test=". = $value_list/val"` - see: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#variable-values.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you do NOT want to create "a sequence of strings". You want to create a string that, when evaluated as an expression, will create a sequence of strings.

Consider something like:

**XSLT 3.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:axsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/TransformAlias">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="axsl" result-prefix="xsl"/>

<xsl:template match="/rules">
    <axsl:stylesheet version="3.0">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </axsl:stylesheet>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rule">
    <axsl:template match="{xPath}">            
        <axsl:if test=". = ({string-join(val/@allow ! concat('''', ., ''''), ',')})">
            <axsl:message>Success</axsl:message>
        </axsl:if>
    </axsl:template>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

P.S. Note that starting a match pattern with `//` does not accomplish anything.

Comment: This works, and I understand the suggested solution. About the // in each match, they come from the source rules, and I think they've been added to let people use them directly in a tool that perhaps parses the entire document and applies the expressions in some XPath functionality. I figured XSLT could solve the checking somehow.

Answer (score 1):

One way, as you have simple string values, would be to store them in an XDM array you serialize as JSON and inject serialized in the generated XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:axsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/TransformAlias"
    version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="true" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
    <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="axsl" result-prefix="xsl"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <axsl:stylesheet>
            <xsl:attribute name="expand-text" select="'true'"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="version" select="'3.0'"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="rules/*"/>
        </axsl:stylesheet>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="rule">

        
        <!-- This also creates ("A", "B") -->
        <xsl:variable name="vals_from_seq_text" as="array(xs:string)" select="array {val/@allow/string() }"/>

        
        <axsl:template>   
        
            <xsl:attribute name="match" select="xPath"/>
            
            <!-- Attempt to move the sequence into the generated template -->
            <axsl:variable name="vals" as="array(xs:string)" select="{serialize($vals_from_seq_text, map{'method':'json'})}"/>

            <axsl:if test=". = $vals?*">
                <axsl:message>Success</axsl:message>
            </axsl:if>
            

        </axsl:template>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This works, and I can see that the result is an array. Could you perhaps point me to some easy to understand source on the map{'method':'json'} part? I really would like to understand theese tools, but I haven't got it by reading the spec unfortunately.

Comment: @Zug_Bug, I suppose you know e.g. `<xsl:output method="html"/>` or `<xsl:output method="text"/>` or `<xsl:output method="xml"/>` to declare the serialization method for an XSLT 2 stylesheet? Well, in XSLT 3 there are two additional methods, one named `json`, one named `adaptive`. In addition the is an XPath 3.1 function named `serialize` that as the first argument takes any XSLT/XDM/XPath sequence and as the second argument the serialization parameters, not in the form of an `xsl:output` declaration, but as an XPath 3.1 "map".

Comment: So all I have done there is to use `<xsl:output method="json"/>`, but in XPath 3.1 syntax, not on the XSLT level. The syntax for XSLT maps is explained in the XSLT 3 spec and the XPath 3.1 spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-maps

Answer (score 1):

It may be simplest to generate the sequence of strings as an XML structure:

```
<axsl:variable name="strings-as-xml" as="element(s)*">
  <xsl:for-each select="$vals_from_seq_text">
    <s>{.}</s>
  </xsl:for-each>
</axsl:variable>

<axsl:variable name="value_list" as="xs:string*"
               select="$strings-as-xml!string()"/>
```

Comment: Another solution that ofcourse works :-) As I asked in another given answer - I'm wondering why my constructed variable containing elements didn't work for comparison? I can get the text value from each included element and run "string()" on it, but I can't get them into a sequence for comparison that I would normally be allowed, if the element node was in the document I was running the XSLT on? Confused...

Comment: I thought you answered that yourself in a comment in your code: your code is generating `<xsl:variable name="..">A B C</xsl:variable>` which is a single string, not a sequence of strings.

Comment: Yes, that one I saw, but I meant the variable $value_list. @michael.hor257k thought it might work if I remove the type from the variable. I'll try that just to see if it works so that I might understand this a bit better.